# Oracle Complex Query performance issue

Tags: oracle

I have a complex sql query where we are fetching data based on criteria and then matching the results returned in that criteria with other sql which have derived columns which are fetched as sub queries.
The issue here is that when We don't have order by clause in the query, it performs really well but when we include sorting it takes 18 secs to return 30 results.
The Data in our database in around 17L records. so I understand sorting will be bit of a problem but it's required.
Please let me know a way in which it can be done a little faster as our SLA for this query is about 3 secs.

Comment: Would need the query, table structure, data volumes, indexes (if any) and query plan to give any reasonable ideas.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Actually would have posted the query but that will be a security risk. What I can tell you is we are using indexes on the columns we are using in the sub query, data volume is 17 Lakhs, query plan gives us cost of 266. Below is the snapshot of the explain plan:

Comment: As I cannot paste all my explain plan here, I can tell you the cost is coming  as 268.

Comment: Sorting thirty records should not take thirty seconds so there must be something else going on. But if you can't post any details there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: lol, in generally that's the way how performing a query

Comment: The cost can be very misleading, the entire query must be taken into account. Yesterday I was working with a complex query against a 2.4M record table. The original had a cost of around 1300 and was taking an hour to run. The second had a cost of about 1.2M (not a typo) and ran in eight minutes.